# is_front_page use in sidebar.php

Tags: theme-development, template-tags, frontpage

I want to introduce some code into sidebar.php dependant on whether the site was on the front page or not. ( I have a static front page and am using the front-page.php file ).

To cut a long story short, I have done some testing and I now have the following code in BOTH my front-page.php file and also in the sidebar.php file; but the two bits of code are displaying conflicting results. The same page is telling me both that I am on front page and not on front page at the same time. The reality is that I actually AM on front page so the question i have is this. Is there something wrong with using the tag is_front_page() in sidebar.php ?

```
if( is_front_page())
       echo "you are on front page";
       else
       echo "you are not on front page";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strange thing - try is_home() . what does that returns ?

Comment: i have sort of figured it out but i am still confused - i moved the position of is_sidebar in the front-page.php file and got a different result - it must have something to do with position relative to the loop or something - i have 2 loops on the page so maybe i've done something wrong with that and confused it

Comment: found it - forgot wp_reset_query() after the second loop